# How to draw one fourth of square grid (triangular way) with tikz so that you can write things inside each cell?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a tikz picture only showing the pink part, and not the rest.
I also want to be able to write things inside, like numbers.
Is this possible?

[image: only the pink part]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `matrix` library is simple:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={draw, minimum size=1em, anchor=center,
                    outer sep=0pt},
             column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth
             ]
{
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 &   \\
   &   & 3 & 4 & 5 &   &   \\
   &   &   & 4 &   &   &   \\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]